# Getting simple Javascript / jQuery to work (ScrollTo by Ariel Flesler)

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATE: Outstanding mr. tpaksu solved my problems and you can see the horizontal ScrollTo in action @** [www.visioville.fi/en/](http://www.visioville.fi/en/)

I had my time fiddling around with CSS, but i came to conclusion that this is pretty much the only thing i cannot get done without Javascript / jQuery.

I've been trying to implement Goro's suggested [jQuery.ScrollTo by Ariel Flesler](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/), but i can't seem to get it working in any way. Add to the fact that i'm a total newbie with Javascript and you'll get my point. I downloaded the newest jQuery and named it as 'jquery.js'

Here's some source:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jquery.js'></script>
</head>
...
<div>
    <p id="gallerytext">...</p>
    <a title="$(div.smallpics).scrollTo( '0%', 800, {axis:'x'} );" id="previmg" href="#image1"></a>
        <div id="smallwindow">
            <div class="smallpics">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#image1"><img alt="Jerseys" src="../images/peliasuja.jpg" /></a></li>
                ...
                <li><a href="#image14"><img alt="Drawing" src="../images/kynailya.jpg" /></a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
    <a title="$(div.smallpics).scrollTo( '50%', 800, {axis:'x'} );" id="nextimg" href="#image8"></a>
</div>
```

And then CSS:

```
#smallwindow    { float:left; overflow/*-y*/: hidden; width:890px; } /* overflow-y whips out the vertical scrollbar */

div.smallpics   { float:left; position:relative;  width:1595px; }

#previmg, #nextimg { float: left; width: 17px; height: 54px; background: white; overflow: hidden; background: url("images/galleryarrows_17x54.jpg"); }
#previmg        { background-position: left top; margin-right: 1px; left top; }
#nextimg        { background-position: right top; position: absolute; float: right; left: 935px; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 1px; }
#previmg:hover  { background-position: left bottom; }
#nextimg:hover  { background-position: right bottom; }

.smallpics ul   { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

.smallpics li   { float: left; text-align: center;  margin-right: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px; white-space: nowrap; }
```

Goro mentioned binding click() event to my arrow buttons, but i don't know what "function" i should type or where to put the code. I'm guessing in front of the .scrollTo event, assuming click() is even needed.

Thank you in advance! You guys are absolutely the best when it comes to programming and coding.

Comment: Several issues as far as I can see. You have put the .scrollTo event code in the title of your anchor. It probably should be in the onclick attribute instead. But when that is done the page complains about JQuery not being initialized.

Comment: Thanks, and as i understand it, you were referring to the same things that tpaksu mentioned also. Wrong sequence in .js files and some added onclick functionalities were needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you need to include your scrollto script AFTER the jquery script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js"></script>
```

and then, you need something like this:

```
$("#nextimg").on("click",function(){
    $("#smallwindow").scrollTo( '50%', 800, {axis:'x'} ); 
});
```

The function inside the click event should change. But once you get this to work, the rest will be easy to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for the good info. It didn't occur to me that the sequence of .js -files mattered (well, i suppose jquery and then everything else), but now that i think of it, it makes all the sense in the world.

I updated the anchor the way you suggested, like so:
`<a title="$("#nextimg").on("click",function(){ $("#smallwindow").scrollTo( '50%', 800 ); });" id="nextimg" href="#image8"></a>`

But it doesn't seem to function. I've stared at that piece of text for quite a while, i'm beginning to get a hunch of how Javascript language works, but even so, i can't seem to notice what i'm lacking :)

Comment: did you make it work? the script shouldn't be on the "title" attribute, it should be inside a `<script type='text/javascript'></script>` code after the `<a>` anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks again tpaksu, you're such an helpful person beyond belief! I thought i tried EVERYTHING and it didn't work, but as i was writing this, it occured to me as last straw: "should i put another of these scripts inside <body>? what do i have to lose?". AND THE MAGIC FINALLY HAPPENED!!! I'm so happy i could almost cry! ;) Though i would've assumed we define this inside <head> and from there i just "call out" to whatever classes or ID's i've scattered inside <body>. It works, but is it meant to work like this? Somehow i get the feeling i could put these on an external file, muchlike with css?

Comment: I actually gave up yesterday night exhausted after a week or more of frustration and this morning i got a build of JCarousel working, but it wasn't as smooth as i hoped and felt outdated. So i opened the .js file to further tinker around with classes and values, and when i saw the code list i thought: _"this doesn't look right nor light and it's from 2006!"._ So i found a new built, which has been posted just last month @ https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel. I didn't manage to implement it yet since scrollTo is working, but it's something to look into if anybody stumbles on this post.

Comment: But now i'm very very happy and i can finally start promoting me and my site properly. I learned a lot from CSS (what to do and what definitely not to), and a bit from Javascript / jQuery thanks to you. If only i could show my gratitude more towards you, but i don't know how. Once again, take these millions of thanks and your name shall be remembered :) And if i ever stop by at Turkey / Istanbul, i'm sure to buy you few Döners (i couldn't think of anything more typical) and thensome. You are a great person tpaksu.